# Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datatable

I need to export all datatables to individual XML files and I cannot export all the rows at once because of System.OutOfMemoryException if there is a huge table. So I tried to export N rows. However WriteXml throws an exception if I use paging syntax in query.

I've tested both queries in LINQPad, they are ok.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize the DataTable.
>   DataTable name is not set.

```
  // The first query causes exception
  string oraQueryGetTableData = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT t0.* FROM MY_TABLE t0) WHERE ROWNUM <= 100";

  // The second query runs without any error
  //oraQueryGetTableData = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE";

  OracleCommand oraCommandGetTableData = new OracleCommand(oraQueryGetTableData, oraConnection);

  OracleDataReader oraReaderTableData = oraCommandGetTableData.ExecuteReader();

  DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
  dataTable.Load(oraReaderTableData);

  // Exception might occur here
  dataTable.WriteXml(writer, true);
```

What is the problem here or how can I fix this?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the line  dataTable.Load(oraReaderTableData); can you see if the data has been properly loaded into dataTable?

Comment: Yes, there are rows.

Comment: Have you tried setting a value to the TableName property of dataTable after loading the reader?

Comment: Adding  dataTable.TableName = "test";  fixed the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the exception says - the table does not have its `TableName` property set. So you just need to set it.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable { TableName = "MyTableName"};
dataTable.Load(oraReaderTableData);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Newtonsoft` to Deserialize the JSON string data to be `DataTable`, the `TableName` attribute will **NOT** be set. I composed the sample code and put the break point after the `dt` assignment to let you see what is `dt.TableName`. The debugging result is shown below:

[image: Sample Code]

So, if you would like to return the `DataTable` as a result of web service method, the `TableName` attribute assignment is needed after `DeserializeObject`. I change the code to be:

```cs
DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(
@"[
    { col1: 'value1', col2: 'value2' },
    { col1: 'value3', col2: 'value4' },
    { col1: 'value5', col2: 'value6' },
]");
dt.TableName = "TableName";
```

And I debug it again. This is The preferable `DataTable` that can be returned by a web method.

[image: Sample Code 2]