# Serialization of class containing DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Is it possible to serialize class that has a property of DataTable type?

Example:

```
public class MyMessage
{ 
    public DataTable Fields { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Most likely DataTable property should be decorated with attributes, but how?

Here is my code:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyMessage));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
var str = xs.Serialize(sw, msg);
```

I receive an exception: *Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set.*

Comment: Is it possible? Did you try?

Comment: I think it's possible, but there are others fields beyond datas. I believe it's not that what you want

Comment: What kind of serialization? There is a `DataTable.WriteXml` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135455.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) is `[Serializable]`, do you have an exception or why do you ask this question? Typically if there is a property of non-serializable type, then you create another property in getter/setter of which you converter to/from non-serializable type and get/set original property value (while marking original property with `[XmlIgnore]`).

Comment: Looks like a dup of [Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35314515) or [Why Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38322181).  Have you tried setting [`DataTable.TableName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename(v=vs.110).aspx) to something as recommended by those answers and the exception message itself?

Answer (score 1):

Mark MyMessage as serialize 
and then like that:

```
 MyMessage test = new MyMessage();
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 table.TableName = "test";
  ...init...
  test.Fields = table;
  using (Stream fs = new FileStream("Test.xml", FileMode.Create))
  {
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyMessage)).Serialize(writer, test);
  }
```

Comment: `XmlSerializer` ignores the `[Serializable]` attribute, there is no need to *Mark MyMessage as serialize*.  What is necessary is to set `table.TableName`.